# checked duplicate name,and values of radio button on page load

Tags: jquery, html

I have 2 sets of the same radio buttons, the one on top of the table and bottom of table (some UI requirements)

The problem is when I set to check the radio button, only the bottom set of the radio buttons is checked

Here is my code:

```
//Top Set of Radio Buttons
<input name="optField"  value="Male" type="radio">Male
<input name="optField"  value="Female" type="radio">Female

//Table Here

//Bottom Set of Radio Buttons
<input name="optField"  value="Male" type="radio">Male
<input name="optField"  value="Female" type="radio">Female
```

Jquery Code:

```
 $(window).load(function(){

 var $radios = $('input[name=optField]');

 $radios.filter('[value="Male"]').attr('checked',true);

 });
```

Comment: So you have duplicate radios, and want the click of one to also click the other with the same value? This seems very odd behaviour.

Comment: So nothing happens when you check the radio buttons at the top?

Comment: I don't get it? If they have the same name, they are in a radio button group, and only **one** can be checked at any given time, not two within the same group, that's the whole point of using radio button, and you **have to** change the name of one group to make that work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify a different name attribute for the two option groups.

**HTML**

```
<input name="optField"  value="Male" type="radio">Male
<input name="optField"  value="Female" type="radio">Female

//Bottom Set of Radio Buttons
<input name="optField2"  value="Male" type="radio">Male
<input name="optField2"  value="Female" type="radio">Female
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var $radios = $('input[name*="optField"]');
    $radios.filter('[value="Male"]').attr('checked',true);
});
```

Comment: You can use the same `name` and put them in a separate `<form>` tag if you want. but still JS part is necessary.